# PythonAnywhere and Celery

Tags: django, celery, pythonanywhere

I am running a Django app on PythonAnywhere. Unfortunately, Celery is not supported (on PythonAnywhere). I would like to use another library like Celery that allows me to execute some process asynchronously (and, icing on the cake, which would also support task scheduling).

Have someone found a solution that is supported by PythonAnywhere?

Could you recommend a user-friendly library just for executing some processes asynchronously?

Comment: Do you try with "Always on tasks"? https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AlwaysOnTasks

Comment: Hi Bast, no I didn't. Thank you for the link but, to be honest, I don't understand how Always-on tasks can execute some process asynchronously?

Comment: I am not very familiar with pythonanywhere, but maybe there is something like webhook, or you can make a while True: connect to a DB and fetch if there is some task (your database will replace redis/rabbitmq and your AlwaysOnTasks act as celery)

Not powerful like redis/celery but this should work

Comment: Agree with @Bast on using an always on task that polls a database to fetch jobs to run asynchronously

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't use SQS free tier from within Python Anywhere, and just install the celery library. Then you could glue Python Anywhere to an instance sitting anywhere. (SQS being essentially a Queue as a Service here.)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Django the easiest way  is to setup an endpoint and calling it periodically using a webhook.
There are a lot of websites that let you set a web process that makes an HTTP call to your endpoint. Just to mention one: https://www.easycron.com.
Have in mind that this might not be the most secure and safe way (allways use HTTPS and define an authentication method to avoid unwanted executions from unwanted calls to your endpoint), but to use it depends on the need of having that feature and the effort of building it.
In Django, the job to be done will be defined in `views.py`.

Another choice, if you can run more than one process in PythonAnywhere, is to build another python script running [apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html).
Check [this](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/master/examples/schedulers/blocking.py) example code.

Comment: Hi Cheche, thank you very much for your answer, I am going to assess your suggestion. Regards

Comment: I would probably not suggest this. Depending on how long the process you are trying to do asynchronously is, this solution (hitting a Django webhook) is not going to work. PythonAnywhere would only allow your process to run for 5min. Also this probably ties up one of your web workers- this means that there will be less workers serving your site to people accessing it. (ie. the site might be slow to load or even fail to load if there are too many asynchronous processes running at once)

Comment: Thank you Conrad, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: check the comments to your question. basically don't do any processing synchronously from your web server. instead offload it to be done asynchronously on a different machine/server. (eg: on "always on tasks" in PythonAnywhere)